# Dependent Equality

Tags: lean4

I have been using lean for a while and I have noticed that I can't actually prove extensionality for my dependent structures. I was worried at first and then noticed that it was essentially dependent equality that I did not have:

```
def dependent_equality (X : Type) (A : X → Type) (x : X) (y : X) (p : x = y) : A x = A y := by sorry
```

For example, `X` could be `Int` and `A` could be `ℤ/nℤ` in the above, in which case I would want an inhabitant of `A n = A m` when `n = m`. I don't know anything about equal types in Lean, but I was more concerned with certain dependent structures whose corresponding extensionality principals had to be made into axioms.

> How does Lean handle dependent equality, or why does it not?

For another more meaningful example, given a structure `S` with possibly dependent entries `e₁,...,eₙ`, I want to be able to show that `(a₁ : e₁) → (b₁ : e₁) → (a₁ = b₁) → S.mk a₁ = S.mk b₁`. With some dependent structures, I have noticed that I can't actually demonstrate extensionality because I get that something isn't "type correct". Meanwhile, it seems that if I was allowed to do multiple rewrites in a row before something was type checked that would solve the problem.

While I am mainly interested in dependent structures up to an equivalence of some kind, I think there are also times where it would be nice to have that property involving `.mk`.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for heterogenous equality `HEq`?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais yes that's exactly what I want. How would you introduce `HEq` and how to you obtain ordinary `=` from `HEq`?

Comment: Look at `eq_of_heq` and `heq_of_eq`. There are some more refined theorems but I think many are currently missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `sorry` with `congr` proves the first one.

For the second question, instead of what you have:

```
S.mk a₁ = S.mk b₁
```

You want to show:

```
S.mk a₁ == S.mk b₁
```

Where `==` is an alias of [`heq`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/core.html#heq), which is a version of `=` that allows two sides to have different types. It can be converted back and forth with `=`, see [this](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/logic/lemmas.html#heq.eq) for example.

Comment: It says there that `Eq.subst` is only for propositions. Is there a substitution for dependent types?

Comment: I took a look and thought that replacing `=` with `heq` may help you the most.

Comment: Oh oh I see, it's HEq that I want. I'm looking for the info on HEq then. Are people ever suspicious of HEq?

Comment: @Cayley-Hamilton It is incompatible with HoTT, but Lean is not HoTT so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Right. How does it work with the forall sign? Can you link me to some rules for HEq?

Comment: @Cayley-Hamilton I'm not sure what do you but perhaps you're asking about funExt (https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/funext.html#funext)? Also checkout my edits.

Comment: Is the double equal the same as the HEq?

Comment: is there funext for HEq?

Comment: You can convert eq to heq and backwards, so funExt on eq is equivalently a funExt on heq